# how to use LaunchNavigator in ionic 5?

Tags: ionic4

Currently im migrating my app from ionic 3 to ionic 5 when i import LaunchNavigator from @ionic-native/launch-navigator it is not showing any error, while compiling the application im getting error like

private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator
[ng]     An argument for 'launchNavigator' was not provided.

But no error is showing in code.

Comment: have you added it to your `app.module.ts` file? also import it like 
`import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator/ngx';`

Comment: Yes i added in app.module.ts but still im getting error while complie" An argument for 'launchNavigator' was not provided." @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: thank you @najam i missed to add navigator in provides in app.module.ts